# threads freezes while catching unhandled exception with setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler (reportDropResult)

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, drag, unhandled-exception

I am getting **java.lang.IllegalStateException: reportDropResult() by non-recipient** exception when I use dragging feature on honeycomb. I want to catch it with using **setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler** to prevent to close application. It enters to the method but after then all threads gets freeze and android appears force close or wait model dialog. I click wait button 10 times but nothing changes. How I prevent this exception and closing the application?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070393/replacing-default-uncaught-exception-handler-to-avoid-crash-dialog this might help you

Answer (score 1):

You cannot stop an app from freezing if you use `setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` it merely gives you the chance to act once happened. Act as in save-your-data or store variable values to a file etc.

You have to call the super to finally show the crash message or else the app hangs forever.

To prevent this exception you have to find out what causes it, not try to somehow catch it and make it go away. Exceptions are Javas FRIENDLY way to tell you, that there is something wrong.

Comment: where i can see in the docs that the app should freeze?